# How can I attach an event listener to a JSLink field?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, jslink

I'm making a custom autocomplete text field, how can I attach javascript events to my control?

Comment: Use the `AddPostRender` method to attach a function in which you can add your event listeners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this excellent article from Andrei Markeev:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms

In a nutshell:

1. RegisterTemplateOverrides for OnPostRender. This will be called after rendering of each field on the form
2. Use the ctx object (parameter to your OnPostRender method) to determine if it is called for your field (ctx.ListSchema.Field will give you field information)
3. You can get the field control Id from the ctx and use it get the field control object and add the event handler to it in standard JS way

Thanks.